# How to see which of the queries in boolean is matched?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have given multiple queries using the bool query. Now it can happen that some of them might have matches and some queries might not have matches in the database. How can I know which of the queries had a match?

For example, here I have a bool query with two should conditions against the field `landMark`.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "landMark": "wendys"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "landMark": "starbucks"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I know which one of them matched in the above query if only one of them matches the documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named query is certainly the way to go.

LINK - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html

Idea of named query is simple , you tag a name to each of your query and in the result , it shows which all tags matched per document.

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/data/data' -d ' { "landMark" : "wendys near starbucks" }'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/data/data' -d ' { "landMark" : "wendys" }'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/data/data' -d ' { "landMark" : "starbucks" }'

Hence create you query in this fashion -

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/data/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "landMark": {
              "query": "wendys",
              "_name": "wendy_is_a_match"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "landMark": {
              "query": "starbucks",
              "_name": "starbuck_is_a_match"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 0.581694,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "data",
      "_type" : "data",
      "_id" : "AVMCNNCY3OZJfBZCJ_tO",
      "_score" : 0.581694,
      "_source": { "landMark" : "wendys near starbucks" },
      "matched_queries" : [ "starbuck_is_a_match", "wendy_is_a_match" ]  ---> "Matched tags
    }, {
      "_index" : "data",
      "_type" : "data",
      "_id" : "AVMCNS0z3OZJfBZCJ_tQ",
      "_score" : 0.1519148,
      "_source": { "landMark" : "starbucks" },
      "matched_queries" : [ "starbuck_is_a_match" ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "data",
      "_type" : "data",
      "_id" : "AVMCNRsF3OZJfBZCJ_tP",
      "_score" : 0.04500804,
      "_source": { "landMark" : "wendys" },
      "matched_queries" : [ "wendy_is_a_match" ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this naming work for every query other than match?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) for this purpose. Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "landMark": {
              "query": "wendys",
              "_name": "wendy match"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "landMark": {
              "query": "starbucks",
              "_name": "starbucks match"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

you can use any `_name` . In response you will get something like this

```
"matched_queries": ["wendy match"]
```

so you will be able to tell which query matched that specific document.